# Grub failed to get canonical path of overlay

Tags: linux, grub, arch-linux, qemu, linux-kvm

So, I've tried to install dwm lately on artix base on Qemu, but I cant get over the installation process. The errors start droppin after I try to install grub. Things I did:

```
cfdisk /dev/vda
```

I ve created two partitons one beeing EFI system of 1G and another of the size 39G beeing Linux Filesystem. Then:

```
mkfs.ext4  /dev/vda2
mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/vda1
mount /dev/vda2 /mnt
mount /dev/vda2 /mnt
mount /dev/vda1 /mnt/boot
basestrap /mnt base base-devel openrc elogind-openrc
basestrap /mnt linux-lts linux-firmware
fstabgen -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Then i've configured the time zone and pacman, after i did this:

```
pacman -S grub os-prober efibootmgr
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub
```

So after that I've met this message:

```
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of 'overlay'
```

Is there any way to fix it without wipin this VM and reinstalling it frm the ground again?

Comment: Either (arch-)chroot /mnt first before you install grub, or use `--efi-directory /mnt/boot` AND `--boot-directory /mnt/boot`

Comment: I had an error message about canonical path of /dev/vdaX on gentoo. Turns out I missed one of the dev binding steps, so I exited the chroot, ran the commands, entered chroot and had access to them again. (I noted I could see them while in the live cd).